# Avoid Seaborn barplot desaturation of colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, palette

I am trying to make plots in Python using several different libraries (`bokeh`, `seaborn` and `matlotlib`), but keeping the same color scheme. I have chosen categorical pallete from bokeh with: 
`from bokeh.palettes import Category10 as palette`
and then also used it in `seaborn` and `matplotlib`. My problem is that, although in `matplotlib` color seem to very similar to `bokeh` (as defined in the palette), `seaborn` shows somehow noticeable darker colors (i.e. less saturated or desaturated) than it should be. I am wondering if it is making some kind of dimming of any color scheme by default and if there is any way to avoid this.
Below there is code for making the same barplot using different libraries 
Using `bokeh`:

```
source = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['exp_1', 'exp_2'], 'data':[3, 5], 'color':palette[10][:2]})
p = bokeh.plotting.figure(x_range=['exp_1', 'exp_2'], y_range=(0,6), plot_height=500, title="test")
p.vbar(x='names', top='data', width=0.9,  legend_field="names", source=source, color='color')
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"
p.legend.location = "top_center"
p.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '22pt'
p.yaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '22pt'
bokeh.io.show(p)
```

Using `matplotlib`:

```
# same palette both for seaborn and matplotlib (taken from bokeh palette)
sns_palette=sns.color_palette(palette[10]) 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.style.use('seaborn')
ax.set_xlabel('experiment', fontsize=20)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=22)
ax.set_xticks([0, 1])
ax.set_xticklabels(['exp_1', 'exp_2'], fontsize=18)
ax.bar([0, 1], source['data'], align='center', color=sns_palette[:2])
```

and using `bokeh`:

```
plt.figure()
ax = sns.barplot(x="names", y="data", data=source, palette=sns_palette[0:2])
ax.set_xlabel('experiment', fontsize=20)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=18)
plt.tight_layout()
```

bokeh barplot: 
[image: bokeh]

matplotlib barplot 
[image: matplotlib]

seaborn barplot: 
[image: seaborn]

Comment: @JohanC doesn't seem to be the reason: I checked, and using white background and also explicit alpha=1 doesn't change the color of barplots: `sns.set_style('white') ;
kwargs = {'alpha':1};
ax = sns.barplot(x="names", y="data", data=source, palette=sns_palette[0:2], **kwargs)`

Comment: [`barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) has an option `saturation` which defaults to `0.75`.  Setting it to `1` avoids all saturation: `sns.barplot(..., saturation=1)` (nonetheless, the documentation recommends some desaturation for aestetic reasons).

Comment: @JohanC Yes, that works! Thanks! (Interestingly this 'desaturation' option by default seem to exist only in barplot and boxplot, but not in lineplot). If you post your comment as an answer I can accept it

Comment: The linked documentation explains that the desaturation is recommended for large areas, so not for lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seaborn chart colors are different than those specified by palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334874/seaborn-chart-colors-are-different-than-those-specified-by-palette)

Answer (score 7):

[Seaborn barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) sets the saturation of the bar face colors to 0.75 by default. This can be overridden by adding `saturation=1` to the barplot call.

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

source = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['exp_1', 'exp_2'], 'data':[3, 5]})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

# default saruration setting
sns.barplot(x="names", y="data", data=source, ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set_title('default saturation')

# additional parameter `saturation=1` passed to barplot
sns.barplot(x="names", y="data", data=source, saturation=1, ax=ax[1])
ax[1].set_title('saturation=1')
```

(This answer is straight form the comment by @JohanC, I'm just elevating it to an answer ... happy for ownership to go to that user.)