# Set Default Saturation in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

The Seaborn's `saturation` is 0.75 by default [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334874/seaborn-chart-colors-are-different-than-those-specified-by-palette). So, one needs to set it to 1 for every new plot. Is it possible to change this default value early on in a notebook? Similar to the `dpi` parameter below in matplotlib.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']= 150

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
sns.countplot(x="class", data=titanic)
plt.figure()
sns.countplot(x="class", data=titanic, saturation=1)
```

[image]

Comment: look into `seaborn.set`

Answer (score 1):

No, seaborn does not define any global settings beyond those in the matplotlib rcParams. But you could use default colors that are more saturated...

Comment: Thanks. Does that also mean that there is no equivalent parameter in matplotlib rcParams? I myself couldn't find any.

Comment: Correct, there is not